# opencv remap function : How to set pixel value to (0,0,0)

Tags: opencv

Function call is:

```
remap( src, dst, map_x, map_y, CV_INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0,0, 0) );

map_x and map_y defines as below:

for( int j = 0; j < src.rows; j++ )
{  for( int i = 0; i < src.cols; i++ ){

      if( i > src.cols*0.25 && i < src.cols*0.75 && j > src.rows*0.25 && j < src.rows*0.75 )
      {
              map_x.at<float>(j,i) = 2*( i - src.cols*0.25 ) + 0.5 ;
              map_y.at<float>(j,i) = 2*( j - src.rows*0.25 ) + 0.5 ;
      }
      else{
              map_x.at<float>(j,i) = 0 ;
              map_y.at<float>(j,i) = 0 ;
       }
   }
}
```

[image: Original Image:]

[image: Result Image:]

You can see the original and resulting image. I want to ask:
How to set the outer parts of the result `image(green part)` to `black(r=0,g=0,b=0)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mapping all pixels on the border to the original pixel at location (0,0). Try to replace the following

```
else {
    map_x.at<float>(j,i) = 0 ;
    map_y.at<float>(j,i) = 0 ;
}
```

by this

```
else {
    map_x.at<float>(j,i) = -1 ;
    map_y.at<float>(j,i) = -1 ;
}
```